# Files type to upload aiff

Tags: php

In a form used to upload music I check the files type, I want to allow people to upload mp3, wav and aiff. I found $_FILES['music']['type'] == 'audio/wav' and $_FILES['music']['type'] == 'audio/mp3' but I can't manage to find the appropriate type for the aiff files. Can anybody help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be worth allowing all audio/* types and then figuring out what to do with them after the fact?

You can check for this like so:

```
// If the mime-type begins with audio/
if (substr($_FILES['musique']['type'], 0, 6) == 'audio/') {
    // Upload the file :-)
}
```

Comment: It could be a great solution actually. But how do I write it? $_FILES['musique']['type'] == 'audio/'* ?

Answer (score 0):

The MIME type of aiff file type is `audio/x-aiff`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, the form act as if the input was empty. I tried with 'aif' and 'aiff' files.